# Why I don't need to pass the required 2 positional arguments in WSGI-compliant apps?

Tags: python, class, wsgi

Here's my class:

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self, environ, start_response):
        self.environ = environ
        self.start_response = start_response    
        self.html = \
        b"""
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Example App</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Example App is working!</h1>
                </body>
            </html>
        """

    def __call__(self):
        self.start_response("200 OK", [("Content-type", "text/html"),
                                        ('Content-Length', str(len(self.html)))])

        return [self.html]
```

And then I run it:

```
app = App()
```

I get a Type Error (obviously) in the Apache error log:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'\r
```

The problem is that every example I saw, they just don't pass those arguments... [This one for example](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.0/the-web-server-gateway-interface-wsgi.html#using-instances-of-classes):

```
class Hello(object):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type','text/plain')])
        return ['Hello World!']

hello = Hello() # ?????????????
```

How am I supposed to pass those arguments and avoid the Type Error, if every example omit them?

Comment: You add environ and start_response to __init__ - why?  Look at the very next example on the page you link for an example of writing an __init__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misread the api doc. Your `__init__` method can take any parameters you want (in your `App` example you probably don't want anything other than self). Then your `__call__` method is the one that needs to have the environ and start_response parameters, and you don't call `__call__` directly, the WSGI server does.

Something like this is what you want..

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   
        self.html = \
        b"""
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{name}</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>{name} is working!</h1>
                </body>
            </html>
        """.format(name=self.name)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        start_response("200 OK", [("Content-type", "text/html"),
                                  ('Content-Length', str(len(self.html)))])

        return [self.html]

app = App('Example App')
```